# Unable to display Formik Form

Tags: javascript, forms, react-native, formik

I am trying to display my formik form, this is the first time I am using this. The screen however is completely blank. I think it has something to do with my styling however I'm not sure. Here is my code:

```
export default class Checkout extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Formik
          initialValues={{first_name: '', last_name: ''}}
          onSubmit={(values) => {
            console.log(values);
          }}>
          {(props) => {
            <View>
              <TextInput
                style={styles.input}
                placeholder="first name"
                onChangeText={props.handleChange('first_name')}
                value={props.values.first_name}
              />
              <TextInput
                style={styles.input}
                placeholder="last name"
                onChangeText={props.handleChange('last_name')}
                value={props.values.last_name}
              />
              <Button
                title="place order"
                color="maroon"
                onPress={props.handleSubmit}
              />
            </View>;
          }}
        </Formik>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  input: {
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: 'black',
    padding: 10,
    fontSize: 18,
    borderRadius: 6,
  },
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using {} then you should return something like this

```
<Formik
          initialValues={{first_name: '', last_name: ''}}
          onSubmit={(values) => {
            console.log(values);
          }}>
          {(props) => {return (<View ...} }
```

or you can remove these {} inside Formik and then no need to type a return statement as you are returning only one thing. Here's what you should do

```
export default class Checkout extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Formik
          initialValues={{first_name: '', last_name: ''}}
          onSubmit={(values) => {
            console.log(values);
          }}>
          {(props) => 
            <View>
              <TextInput
                style={styles.input}
                placeholder="first name"
                onChangeText={props.handleChange('first_name')}
                value={props.values.first_name}
              />
              <TextInput
                style={styles.input}
                placeholder="last name"
                onChangeText={props.handleChange('last_name')}
                value={props.values.last_name}
              />
              <Button
                title="place order"
                color="maroon"
                onPress={props.handleSubmit}
              />
            </View>;
          }
        </Formik>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```